# How does Rutger Map interpolate base pairs (bp)?

Tags: dna

I'm trying to use the Rutger's Map Interpolater to calculate the centiMorgan for a specific base pair (bp).

How does the interpolater interpolate?

So for example I am interested in finding the cM for segment 227193370. The website gives me a female (Kos cm) of 305.9893276210580 but when I download the map data (v3) and I look in the file, the nearest bp is 227193368 and 227193396. So I'm wondering how the website actually derives the number for the specific bp.

http://compgen.rutgers.edu/map_interpolator.shtml

Comment: Although I answered this question, it is a more suitable question for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ than it is for this Genealogy & Family History stackexchange site.

Answer (score 2):

The Rutgers interpolater uses linear interpolation of the smoothed map positions.

The Rutgers smoothed map was made to facilitate interpolation of map positions for markers that are not on the Rutgers map. See the paper: [A second-generation combined linkage-physical map of the human genome, by Matise, et al, 2007](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2099587/).

You didn't say in your question what chromosome you were looking up, but your example values only occur on chromosome 1. I can also tell from your values that you are using the correct file RUMapv3_B137_chr1.txt which is the smoothed file.

From the smoothed file, your data on chromosome 1 is:

```
X1 = 227193368, Y1 = 305.989326207143
X2 = 227193396, Y2 = 305.989346001949
```

You want to know what Y3 is, given:

```
X3 = 227193370
```

The linear interpolation equation is:

```
Y3 = Y1 + (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1) * (X3 - X1)
```

which calculated in a spreadsheet gives me:

```
305.9893276
```

And that is what you said the Rutgers interpolator gave you.